# Unable to access the variable which is declared as global variable and initialized inside the click function

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I am trying to access the variable which is declared as global variable and initialized inside the `onclick` function.

It's not accessible outside the `onclick` function.

In below code "`ClickedChillerName`" is variable which I declared as global and initialized in `onclicked` function.
After click is happening I am reloading the page.

Though I want to access "`ClickedChillerName`" outside it's giving undefined.

```
window.onload = function() {
  initAuth('Line chart and events table using the PAYG SKU');  // initiate auth objects, header, and login modal
  var tsiClient = new TsiClient();
  //var ChillerName;
  var linechartTsqExpressions = [];
  var startDate = new Date('2021-01-27T04:20:00Z');
  console.log('date : '+startDate);
  var endDate = new Date(startDate.valueOf() + 1000*60*60*4);
  //var ClickedChillerName;
  console.log("step4"+ClickedChillerName);
  linechartTsqExpressions.push(new tsiClient.ux.TsqExpression({timeSeriesId: [ClickedChillerName]}, // instance json
    {Max: {
      kind: 'numeric',
      value: {tsx: '$event.temperature.Double'},
      filter: null,
      aggregation: {tsx: 'max($value)'}
    }}, // variable json
    { from: startDate, to: endDate, bucketSize: '1m' }, 
     '#60B9AE', // color
     'MaxValue')); // alias

  // onInstanceClick Function start
  var onInstanceClick = function(instance) { 
    $(".tsi-name").click(function() {
      console.log(this.innerHTML);
      window.location.reload();
      ClickedChillerName=this.innerHTML;
      console.log(ClickedChillerName+"Name");
      console.log("Step1");
    });

    console.log(ClickedChillerName+"Name2");
    console.log("Step2");
    let contextMenuActions = [];
    authContext.getTsiToken()
      .then(token => { 
        tsiClient.server.getTimeseriesTypes(token, 'Test.env.timeseries.azure.com', [instance.type.id])
        .then(r => {
          if (r.get && Array.isArray(r.get)) {
            r.get.forEach((t) => {
              let type = t.timeSeriesType;
              Object.keys(type.variables).forEach((vName) => {
                let option = {};
                if (type.variables[vName].aggregation.tsx === 'avg($value)') {
                  let newType = this.getTsmTypeFromVariable(type.variables[vName]);
                  option['name'] = vName;
                  option['action'] = () => addInstanceAction(newType, vName, instance);
                } else {
                  option['name'] = vName;
                  option['action'] = () => addInstanceAction(instance.type, vName, instance);
                }
                contextMenuActions.push(option);
              });
            });
          hierarchy.drawContextMenu(contextMenuActions, {});
          }
        })
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. You have posted FAR TOO MUCH code. Please edit the snippet and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Edited the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

**Understanding JavaScript Scope**

In JavaScript there are two types of scope:

Local scope
Global scope

JavaScript has function scope: Each function creates a new scope.

**Variables defined inside a function are not accessible (visible) from outside the function.**

Local JavaScript Variables
Variables declared within a JavaScript function, become LOCAL to the function.

Local variables have Function scope: They can only be accessed from within the function.

```
// code here can NOT use carName

function myFunction() {
  var carName = "Volvo";

// code here CAN use carName

}
```

so your //var ClickedChillerName; is local to the function, that is why you can access it from outside - the "undefined" value you got.

**Global JavaScript Variables**
A variable declared outside a function, becomes GLOBAL.

A global variable has global scope: All scripts and functions on a web page can access it.

```
var carName = "Volvo";

// code here can use carName

function myFunction() {

// code here can also use carName

}
```

more information here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Hi Ridwan
Tq for answering it.
But I have declared variable outside of function and just initialization/assiging value is happening inside onclick function.
So,I beleive that var has to be accessed outside anywhere.

Comment: when you declare a variable like this

    // Declare at the beginning
     var firstName, lastName, price, discount, fullPrice;

      // Use later (inside a function or wherever - it will work)
      firstName = "John";
      lastName = "Doe";

      price = 19.90;
      discount = 0.10;